# Golang, Docker, external packages, not finding path

Tags: docker, go

My dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.14
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

error:

```
main.go:11:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH)
```

My PATH in GOPATH is

```
GOPATH=/Users/pstrom/go
```

I'm coming from a javascript background and there you run `NPM INSTALL` which adds all external packages to directory `node_modules` in same directory as the project.

Is there any similar command in Go? Can't find any. I don't want add any PATH in docker, because I wanna run it from anywhere.

How do I handle external packages in Docker in Go?

Comment: See the [docs for go modules](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Modules__module_versions__and_more) (this help is also displayed when you type `go help modules` at the command line). GOPATH is no longer needed, replaced by go modules.

Comment: Add the line `RUN go get` before the build line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the comments too.

It's possible you need to create a `go.mod` file which functions like `package.json`. If you don't have a `go.mod` file but just want to get going, you can `go mod init x` in the directory alongside `main.go` and `Dockerfile`. Then, to force packages to be added to `go.mod`, you can just `go run .` (or `go run main.go`).

Then:

```
FROM golang:1.15

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main .
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/main"]
```

- I recommend bumping to Go 1.15
- `WORKDIR` creates the directory if not present so you skip the `mkdir`
- `/app` is outside of `${GOPATH}` which is correct when using modules
- `COPY` >> `ADD` (my preference)
- `go mod download` gets dependencies defined in `go.mod`
- `COPY . .` everything else, may just need to be `COPY main.go .`
- `ENTRYPOINT` >> `CMD` and the container will default to running your binary